# BxSlider - Custom Next button per slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

What I am trying to achieve is... a form within a slider.

You are asked one question, then you click a button and it takes you to the next slide with a different question and so on... Below is an example of the steps. (each blue box is a new slide)

[image]

I would like a custom next button for each slide on BxSlider. But can figure out how to do this.

So far I am here: http://pagedev.co.uk/alltransfers/

I do not know how to change the name of the next tag for each slide using the java. I would just like to be able to paste some text into each list item and use it as the next element...

Im hoping its something simple!

My html is:

```
<div class="book-slider-container">
    <span id="slider-next"></span>

    <ul id="top-slider">

        <li>
            <h4>Whats your destination?</h4>
            <div class="destination">
                <div class="full-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>


        <li>
            <h4>Where are you going?</h4>
            <div class="destination">
                <div class="full-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h4>Choose Your Vehicle</h4>
            <div class="destination">
                <div class="full-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h4>Whats your destination?</h4>
            <div class="destination">
                <div class="full-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width:970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {

    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(../images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: -8%;
    background: url(../images/prev.png);
    width: 29px;
    height: 68px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: -8%;
    background: url(../images/next.png);
    width: 29px;
    height: 68px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}




/* Booking Slider */
.book-slider-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:30% 0% 30% 0%;
    z-index:999;
}

.book-slider-container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
}

#slider-next    {
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:24px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffffff;

    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-49px;
    z-index:99999;
}

#slider-next a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#slider-next a:hover {
    color:#ffc200;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffc200;
}

#book-slider {
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;

}

.book-slider-wrapper li {
    background-color:#219eff;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:2% 0px;
    margin-right:5%;

    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 12px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}

.book-slider-wrapper li h4 {
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:27px;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}


.book-slider-wrapper li .destination {
    width:70%;
    height:65px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:15%;
    text-align:left;

    background: url(../images/footer-book-icon.png) no-repeat left; 
    background-size:15%;
    background-color:#ffffff;

    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.book-slider-wrapper li .full-input input  {
    width:90%;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:20px;

    border-left:1px solid #bcc0c6;

    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:21px;
    line-height:25px;
    color:#313943;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

JS being called:

```
<script src="js/bxslider.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#top-slider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        moveSlides: 1,
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        nextText: 'Lets Go',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you could use the [`onSlideAfter` callback](http://bxslider.com/options#onSlideAfter) and change the css of the next button depending on which slide index you are on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of **[`onSlideAfter`](http://bxslider.com/options)** option of `bxslider` and change text accordingly.

> **onSlideAfter**
>
> *Executes immediately after each slide transition. Function argument is the current slide element (when transition completes).*
>
> **default:** *function(){}*
>
> **options:** *function($slideElement,
>   oldIndex, newIndex){ // your code here }*
>
> **arguments:**
>
> **$slideElement:** *jQuery element of the destination element*
>   **oldIndex:** *element index of the previous slide (before the transition)*
>   **newIndex:** *element index of the destination slide (after the transition)*

Modify you Last 2 `li` with extra `data-*` attributes as below:

```
<li data-next-text="Choose my car">
   <h4>Choose Your Vehicle</h4>
   <div class="destination">
      <div class="full-input">
         <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
      </div>
   </div>
<li>

<li data-next-text="My Details">
    <h4>Whats your destination?</h4>
    <div class="destination">
         <div class="full-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
         </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Add the above `function` to your plugin initialization

```
$('#top-slider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        moveSlides: 1,
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        nextText: 'Lets Go',
        onSlideAfter:function($slideElement,oldIndex, newIndex){
            var newText=$slideElement.next().data('next-text'); 
            //newText will have data from its next sibling
            $('.bx-next').text(newText);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom next button, an element that you have created, on click use goToSlide() (read more in Public Methods section here: http://bxslider.com/options)
Example:

```
<li>
    <h4>Where are you going?</h4>
    <div class="destination">
        <div class="full-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..."></input>
        </div>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="next-button" data-target="3">Next Question</a>
</li>

$('.next-button').click(function() {
    var slideNumber = $(this).data('target');
    slider.goToSlide(slideNumber);
});
```